# How to make 2 views fill the screen horizontally?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

How to make the 2 TextInputs fill the screen's width? I also want a small space between them

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEST 1"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEST 2"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

How it looks like now:
[image]

How I want it to look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `weightSum`. Please see edited XML. Take note of the `paddingEnd`, `paddingLeft` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` I added.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST 1"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST 2"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `margin` instead of `padding` for space between views...